# Can't get log4net working in MVC3 sub-classed controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, log4net

I have an MVC3 application that I'd like to get log4net working in.
I got the code I'm using from [this site](http://basquang.wordpress.com/2011/08/26/logging-using-log4net-in-asp-net-mvc-3/)

I can get the logging to work if I add this code to an Action method.

```
  public ActionResult Index() {  
      log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(this.GetType());  
      log.Info("Here I am in Index.");   
      return View();  
  }
```

I'd like to enable logging in all my controllers, so I added the following class to my project,

```
  public class LoggingController :Controller {
      protected log4net.ILog Log;

      public LoggingController () {
          Log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(GetType());
      }
  }
```

and I'm having my Home controller inherit from this class, LoggingController.

I've put a break point on my LoggingController's constructor and determined the constructor is being called, however my logging isn't working when done this way.

My question then is:

Why isn't this working? 
OR
Is there a better way of accomplishing what I'm trying to do here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's your web.config and assemblyinfo look like?

Comment: If you look at the link I posted in my question, it is the same. The only difference is the connection string.  I found that this is working, but only if I stop the application, make a change to the source code and then recompile. There seems to be something wrong with the way log4net is flushing it's logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why isn't this working?

Because the type argument you pass to the `GetLogger` method must match that of the containing type. You are passing HomeController (by using `GetType()`) instead of LoggingController which is where the variable is declared. Try like this:

```
public LoggingController () {
    Log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
}
```